# All possible sequences within the number of length N with given condition

Tags: c++, regex, string, algorithm, substring

For example we got string "Number" of length 5 (n = 5) which consists of all digits from 1 to a (digits may be repeated but all digits from 1 to a must be included in the string and the string must have length of n). Let's say a = 2 and generate exemplary number (or rather sequence of digits) with previously given conditions, let it be "12211" which has length of 5 and consists of ones and twos. Now lets assume we need to find an algorithm that will find all the possible sequences of digits within our string "Number" where each sequence is substring of "Number", each with various length which may contain only one occurrence of any digit.

For our example "12211" we can say that there are 7 sequences:

```
1.    "1"
2.    "12"
3.    "2"
4.    "2"
5.    "21"
6.    "1"
7.    "1"
```

Result will be "7".

Another example for clarity : for "Number" = "123452" and b = 5 (digits are 1,2,3,4,5) possible sequences are:

```
1.    "12345"
2.    "1234"
3.    "123"
4.    "12"
5.    "1"
6.    "2345"
7.    "234"
8.    "23"
9.    "2"
10.   "3452"
11.   "345"
12.   "34"
13.   "3"
14.   "452"
15.   "45"
16.   "4"
17.   "52"
18.   "5"
19.   "2"
```

Result will be "19".

Do you have any ideas for fast algorithm for that? The one I came up with is too slow (compares every digit).

Comment: Do you want the number of substrings or do you want them all printed out? And what is an acceptable time complexity for the algorithm?

Comment: Read carefully I wrote number of substrings. I think it could be done in O(n) but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is O(n) problem, if you will use O(1) time set. Look to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a boolean table as a set (true in nth element means n is in actual interval)

Now it's easy. You should just iterate through the array and expand the interval, when you find repeated element, you just move begin of interval until you reach unique sequence.

Some code for better explanation:

```
unsigned long long number_of_seq(string seq) {
  set<char> in_use; //Can be some O(1) set, pointless
  unsigned long long result = 0ULL;
  //p - begin of actual interval
  //q - end of this interval
  for(size_t p = 0, q = 0; q < seq.size();) {
       while(in_use.count(seq[q]) != 0) { //While: add seq[q] makes interval not unique
            in_use.erase(seq[p]);
            ++p; //move begin of interval
        }
       in_use.insert(seq[q]);
       ++q;
       result += q - p; //add size of interval
   }
  return result;
 }
```

You should add size of any interval, cause you just add new element on end, all substring are correct (there no 2 same characters), and all substring without new character are considered. It's a largest unique substring in seq[0:q] with seq[q], so it's correct.

Comment: I did something similar (with boolean table) but it's working too slow.

Comment: @MichałKryszak That solution is O(n), if you don't want to print all intervals. O(n³) if you want, because here can be n² correct sequences. I strongly believe that will be hard to overcome.

Comment: I guess it's working... although i don't quite understand all code... Thanks.

Comment: I think I need to improve my data structures a lot to get better at algorithms :P

Comment: However this code fails for bigger input making it kinda of useless.

Comment: I'm little bit confused. How big input?

Comment: I don't want to extend discussion in comments (got a warning) but length of a sequence (n) may be up to 1,000,000 and may consists of 300,000 different numbers.

Comment: That's true. Make sure you are using `ULL`, and set of type with 300K different possible values. I hope you can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), check the section with "Reading out all LCSs" and with smart use of the matrix, you'll get all you need.

Comment: The OP is asking about substrings, not subsequences. Are you sure this is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count(std::string seq, int len) {
   int sum = 0;
   bool elem[256] = {0};
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while ( i < len ) {
      while ( !elem[seq[j]] && j < len) {
         elem[seq[j]] = true;
         j++;
      }
      sum += j - i;
      elem[seq[i]] = false;
      i++;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

I can't think of a more efficient solution than that. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think `std::string[]` is that, what you want.

Comment: You are not taken into account some chars after detecting collision. This solution is incorrect. Take examples from OP's post.